# setup for phpstorm vagrant xdebug

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

Here is my setup :

Vagrant **scotchbox** on which i installed `sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug`

Host = Windows 8.1, Virtualbox = Ubuntu

I have xdebug installed (proof of the php -v) :

```
PHP 5.5.26-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Jun 15 2015 10:04:01)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

Here is my x-debug.ini :

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "phpstorm"`
```

Now here is my server on phpstorm : path are fine

[image: config]
[image: xdebug]

**My procedure**

First i'm trying via web browser lauching a simple symfony web application via Phpstorm.

1. i click on the icon that listen to debug connection
2. i launch debug on my php dev.portfolio.jules
3. its starts a debugging session with the following error : Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'phpstorm'

The problem is that it doesn't even open a chrome tab or something..

What am i missing ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what's does not work? How do you debug (1. CLI or via web browser?; 2. Actual procedure in few words)? Please provide xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session.

Comment: I add my procedure in edit. Where can i find logs ?

Comment: Is port config on vagrant box correct? I.e. - not blocked by firewall?

Comment: 1) http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log 2) Please show xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured via browser.

Comment: *"its starts a debugging session with the following error : Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'phpstorm'"* That's not an error at all -- normal working message.